# Displaying calendar events as text, in the terminal

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, command-line, calendar

Using Yosemite, is there a way to display events from my calendar in the command line?

I'm aware of the stock calendars apple supplies for things like holidays and such, /usr/share/calendar/ and the command 'calendar' to display events listed in these. Is there a way to do the same thing but list events from my own calendars?

I've found that personal calendars are stored in ~/Library/Calendars but everything I've found within that folder does not work with the 'calendar' command. There are several folders with ambiguous names similar to "D4385-GS57-D352-GA248592.calendar". And some folders contain a lot of *.ics files, which I think are calendar events.

Comment: `calendar` doesn't work with *.ics files, see `man calendar` for the supported file format. But I'm curious whether there are some other means to list the content of your calendar in a readable form.

Comment: @patrix That's right. I read through the man page when I found out about this command. I don't know too much about how the calendars work in modern OS X, but I think the *.ics files are calendar entries. What you mentioned is what I'm looking for, some other means to list the calendar contents in text form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about something like that:

```
$ find ~/Library/Calendars -name "*.ics" |
      xargs grep -h -e "SUMMARY" -e "DTSTAMP" |
      sed -E 's/^[A-Z].*:(.*$)/\1/g' |
      sed -E 's/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*$/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/g'
Fist’s Birthday
2014-05-16 05:44:20
Secon’s Birthday
2014-07-26 09:58:49
Third’s Birthday
2014-05-16 05:44:20
...
```

This command will output all events in all your calendars (included subscribed ones).

Comment: This is great, I'm working through a sed beginners guide right now to learn how this works. I hope to learn enough to filter events by date. Ideally I would like to be able to pass a command that shows events for the current day and maybe five days out.

Comment: If you are getting error: **xargs: grep: Argument list too long** Use: `cd ~/Library/Calendars/; grep -r -h -e "SUMMARY" -e "DTSTAMP" . --include='*.ics'` for the first part until sed's.

Answer (score 14):

I like to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install a version of icalbuddy that works fine with OS X 10.11

```
brew install ical-buddy
```

from [hasseg.org/icalBuddy/](https://hasseg.org/icalBuddy/)

> icalBuddy is a command-line utility that can be used to get lists of
> events and tasks/to-do's from the OS X calendar database (the same one
> iCal uses).

Comment: Homebrew version can now be found at: `brew install ical-buddy`. Note the dash.

Comment: Excellent, I needed the titles of all my events of tomorrow, which is this: `icalBuddy -eep '*' -nc 'eventsToday+1'`

Answer (score 10):

You should look into icalbuddy http://hasseg.org/icalBuddy/ . This lets you configure what days you want to output, by date/calendar and all fields. It actually interacts great with calendars of all kinds (synced and not) and can be used in terminal, geektool, etc.

Comment: FYI - iCalBuddy is great but there is a bug with OS X 10.11 reported here: https://github.com/ali-rantakari/icalBuddy/issues/14

Comment: It seems to be fix since then.