# Can I assign a custom alert time to a calendar entry?

Tags: calendar, ical

I want to have an alert 90 minutes before a calendar event. That isn't an option in Calendar on iOS. Fantistical has more alert time options than Calendar so I imagine there's a way to set an arbitrary alert time. Is there a way to do that from the command line or a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the Calendar app you can setup a custom alert per entry. Here I've added an item to my Calendar and then double clicked on it to open up a dialog to customize. Under that menu is an alert section under the time/date area of the calendar entry, in that menu select customize.

*Calendar entry dialog*

[image: ss1]

*Alert menu*

[image: ss2]

*Customize menu*

[image: ss3]

*You can setup either an email or an audible sound for your specific time*

[image: ss4]

#### CLI access to Calendar

You could use [icalBuddy](http://hasseg.org/icalBuddy/) which was recommended in this other AD Q&A titled: [Displaying calendar events as text, in the terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162206/displaying-calendar-events-as-text-in-the-terminal).

#### References

- [Set event alerts and receive notifications in Calendar on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/set-event-alerts-and-receive-notifications-icl1012/11.0/mac/10.14)

Comment: I was hoping to do it in iOS, but I did mention the command line so a macOS solution is perfectly valid. I just hadn't looked on my iMac yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly workaround on iOS:

1. make sure you have a Google account;
2. install Google Calendar for iOS;
3. add your event in Google Calendar, which *does* allow you to set a custom alarm time;
4. add the Google account to iOS settings and make sure to include calendar data;
5. optionally, once you have your Google calendar also showing up in the iOS built-in calendar, you can use the iOS build-in calendar to move the event from Google into the iOS calendar, which will keep the custom alarm time.